# Could call a method with the parameters are array

Tags: java, jxl

I have a class

```
public class datatonghop{
    private float[] dinhMucChinh;
    private String[] nhanCong;
    public float[] getDinhMucChinh() {
        return dinhMucChinh;
    }
    public void setDinhMucChinh(float[] dinhMucChinh) {
        this.dinhMucChinh = dinhMucChinh;
    }
    public String[] getNhanCong() {
        return nhanCong;
    }
    public void setNhanCong(String[] nhanCong) {
        this.nhanCong = nhanCong;
    }
}
```

and 1 class : I've already written down `addNumberFloat` method

```
public class Report{
   public void getReport(WritableSheet sheet,datatonghop db){
      addNumberFloat(sheet, 4, 10, db.getDinhMucChinh()[0], libs_excel.boder_content_13_d_heso);
   } 
}
```

How could I add database into `float[] dinhMucChinh` and use `getReport` in main

Comment: From your main class, first create an instance of `datatonghop` class. then call `setDinhMucChinh(<float array data>)` . Now , you have your data ready. Create an instance of `Report` class and call instance method `getReport` on `Report`'s instance where you pass your `sheet` and the prepared data i.e. instance of `datatonghop` which already has float array populated in required field.   p.s. Use Java naming convention whilenaming your classes.

Comment: First start a class name with a capital letter.